# What does $0 stand for in following bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

first script

```
seq 9 | awk '{ lifo[NR]=$0 } END{for{lno=NR; lno>-1 lno--}print lifo[lno];}'
```

second script

```
egrep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]+\b" $filename |\ 

awk '{count[$0]++'} 

END {
for(ind in count)


{printf ("%-14s%d\n",ind,count[int]);}

}'
```

First example is reverse printing of a file and second is to count unique words in file and print them along with no. of there appearance.

file

```
sam 
dad
dad
```

output of 2nd:

```
sam 1

dad 2
```

In both the scripts how is `$0` working? 
echo `$0` prints the shell used.

Comment: work your way thru the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seq 9 | awk '{ lifo[NR]=$0 } END{for{lno=NR; lno>-1 lno--}print lifo[lno];}'
```

see the single quotes, they are avoiding the shell to interpret the `$0` which is then interpreted by `awk` as the *whole input line*.